# I want to import CSV file, a list of group members to Distribution group name is ibv europa, but following script not working

Tags: powershell, scripting, exchange-server

```
$users = import-csv "c:\temp\merged11.csv" | ForEach-Object {Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "IBV Europa" }
```

we have removed "" from CSV file and it's now include only column of all email addresses.

I have tried different syntax's but won't helpful.

Comment: Sounds like you should probably put the `"`'s back in :)

Comment: Show us the first couple of lines of that CSV. Have a look at what [Add-DistributionGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/add-distributiongroupmember?view=exchange-ps#-member) wants for parameter `-Member`

Answer (score 0):

If you just have one column with the mail addresses, i would use get-content instead of import-csv and remove the header from the csv file.

merged11.csv Example:

```
User1@test.com
User2@test.com
User3@test.com
```

and the Powershell Script could be like this:

```
$UserEMailList = get-content "c:\temp\merged11.csv"
$UserEMailList | ForEach-Object {
     Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "IBV Europa" -Member $_ 
}
```